# How to access and create if statement variables C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to keep to the DRY principle in C#, and I was wondering if it's possible to access the argument checks in an `if` block. For example, would the below be possible?

```
if (foo == true || bar == false)
{
  if (check0)
  {
    //foo is true
  }
  if (!check1)
  {
    //bar is false
  }
}
```

I was also wondering if it's possible to do this, to keep the scope clean?:

```
if (var foo = runTimeAccessedVariable == "bar")
{
  //we now have the runtime generated variable.
}
//but it doesn't exist here
```

Comment: Are there any object oriented languages that support this?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: OK apologies @Heinzi, they have both already been answered but I will remember that

Comment: C++ allows assignment-expressions. They were more trouble than they were worth (people didn't spot the assignments, and spelling mistakes e.g. = instead of == did not cause errors) so they were not included in C#

Comment: The outer `if` is entirely unnecessary. Can you give a real example?

Comment: @CodeCaster If you had a huge code block that you wanted to run for multiple checks (in order), but only certain parts could run if certain criteria were met, then this would be extremely helpful. It would also allow for a cleaner scope (out of the `if` statement), and wouldn't violate the DRY principle by running the check inside the if again.

Comment: My advice would be to break up that code block into smaller method that return useful variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible. In fact, since you use the short-circuiting `||`  operator, the second check might not even be evaluated.

Obviously, you can work around it as follows:

```
var fooIsTrue = (foo == true);
var barIsFalse = (bar == false);

if (fooIsTrue || barIsFalse)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that this changes the behaviour of your code, since `barIsFalse` is always evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. What about the second idea?

Comment: you could perhaps use a using statement on objects that are disposable

Comment: or perhaps a Func or an Action

Answer (score 2):

The scope and reuse can both be trivially solved by using a pair of brackets to define a new scope;

```
pulic void MyFunc() 
{

    // do stuff here in the scope of MyFunc

    {
        // create child scope with new scoping rules and declare control variables
        var fooTrue = foo == true;
        var barFalse = bar== false;
        if (fooTrue || barFalse)
        {
            if (fooTrue)
            {
                //foo is true
            }
            if (barFalse)
            {
                //bar is false
            }
        }
    }

   // stuff here cannot access fooTrue, barFalse.
}
```

This stops the variables from 'leaking out' of this part of the function. There is a small semantic difference because the `var barFalse` line isn't shortcut, but it seems from your example that you'll probably need to test it anyway so it shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Answering you second question, no it is not possible to declare a variable in this way. The only similar alternative is to use `{ }` to create your own local scope and declare the local variable before the `if` statement:

```
{
    bool foo;

    if (foo = runTimeAccessedVariable == "bar")
    {

    }
}
```

In any case I'm not really sure what the benefits of this approach are. If you are insde the `if` statement, you already know `foo` is `true`, what is the use of having the scoped local?

Concerning your first question, I'd just push back on the whole approach. You are basically using an `if` statement based on a boolean expression made up of two or more conditions. Then, once inside the `if` statement you are discerning between what boolean condition is met or not. Also, you could have the case of an uninitialized variable, because `check1` is not guaranteed to run.

I'd rewrite that completely and by-pass the need of any locally scoped variables:

1. Work is independent for each condition:

   ```
   if (foo)
   {
       //whatever
   }
   else if (bar)
   {
       //whatever
   }
   ```
2. There is common work for both conditions:

   ```
   if (foo)
   {
       //whatever

       if (bar)
       {
           //whatever
       }
   }
   ```

   Both would be semantically equivalent to what you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually. You can use (extension) methods like this:

```
// For first case.
public static void If(this Lazy<bool>[] checks, Predicate<Lazy<bool>[]> ifCondition, Action<Lazy<bool>[]> ifAction) {
    if (ifCondition(checks)) ifAction(checks);
}

// For second case.
public static void If(this object[] variables, Predicate<object[]> ifCondition, Action<object[]> ifAction) {
    if (ifCondition(variables)) ifAction(variables);
}
```

And use of it would look like this:

```
// First case.
new[] { new Lazy<bool>(() => foo == true), new Lazy<bool>(() => bar == false) }.
    If(checks => checks[0].Value || checks[1].Value, checks => {
    if (checks[0].Value) {
        //foo is true
    }
    if (!checks[1].Value) {
        //bar is false
    }
});

// Second case.
new[] { "bar" }.If(variables => (string)variables[0] == "bar", variables => {
    //we now have the runtime generated variable.
});
```

This will limit the scope of those temporary values. However, this does not provide any check for whether you actually using `checks` or `variables` in the right way. And it would be harder to debug if something goes wrong then simple `if` statement.

This could also be extended to accept `Func` instead of `Action` that your `If` method could `return` result as well. And it is possible to even add `ElseIf` and `Else` methods to chain with `If` method (to mimic all `if` statement behavior).